# How do I exclude things that match the specified path for an HttpHandler in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler

I know that if I want to have requests for MyPage.aspx go to the class called MyHandler in the assembly called MyAssembly, I can add this to my web.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="MyPage.aspx" type="MyHandler, MyAssembly"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This works for any MyPage.aspx at the (made up) URL: www.mycoolsite.com/MyProject/[SomePathHere]/MyPage.aspx

What if I want to do it for every MyPage.aspx *except* www.mycoolsite.com/MyProject/NoHandler/MyPage.aspx

Is there a way to exclude that path from the handler?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put a web.config in the `NoHandler` folder that defines a different handler (NotFound if you want to server a 404 style, etc).  Same format as your current `web.config`, just put only the elements you want to override like the handler.

Here's an example if you want to override with a 404 in that directory:

```
<configuration>
 <system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
   <remove verb="*" path="MyPage.aspx" type="MyHandler, MyAssembly"/>
   <add verb="*" path="MyPage.aspx" type="MySpecialHandler, MyAssembly"/>
  </httpHandlers>
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: If something matches both paths what determines priority?  I mean, am I guaranteed that `<add verb="*" path="NoHandler/MyPage.aspx" type="MySpecialHandler, MyAssembly"/>` would win out over `<add verb="*" path="MyPage.aspx" type="MyHandler, MyAssembly"/>`

Comment: @Tim - Updated the answer with an example, there's also a remove option you can use for your case :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, Nick.  This solution worked for me, except that I had to take out the "type" from the remove ... otherwise it was giving me an error.