# IIS Handlers exclude a Directory when processing htm requests

Tags: asp.net, iis-8, handlers, iis-handlers

I am using the below handler in by web.config file. The problem i am now faced with is that i have `.htm` files in a particular directory that i need to be excluded from this handler. Is there a way to do this?

```
<add name="ASPNETLikeHandler-Classichtm" path="*.htm" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode" />
```

So when a certain directory is targeted i want the `.htm` files to behave as they would by default.
Is this even possible?

Comment: is this solution applicable?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509770/how-do-i-exclude-things-that-match-the-specified-path-for-an-httphandler-in-asp

Comment: @rogerdeuce the sudo code they're is making it a little confusing for me to see how i could apply that to my situation.  I need to basically say don't apply handler when a request is made for this directory.  Kind of like a precondition but i didn't see any valid preconditions that i could apply to make this happen.

Comment: I've haven't had the pleasure of using these yet but, it looks like you can exclude a specific directory.  I think you would use the remove syntax in that answer, along with the directory option listed in 'UI elements for handler mappings' here:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831697.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Place a web.config file into the directory you want ignored and remove the handler

```
<system.webServer>
     <handlers>
       <remove name="ASPNETLikeHandler-Classichtm" />
     </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I am doing the exact same thing as the OP, this solution fixed the Server 500 errors I was getting.