# IIS Rewrite, with the swagger ui giving 404 not found error

Tags: swagger-ui, asp.net-core-3.1, url-rewrite-module

I am hosting Dotnet Core 3.1 project with a Vue js application. For that, I have hosted the vue js static files inside the www-root folder.

I also have a swagger UI in my application.

This is the default web config that I have in the hosted directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" 
                stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

With this configuration, the swagger ui runs fine without any error.

But I have to add the rewrite logic for the Vue js application, so I have updated the web config with the following configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="wwwroot-static" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="([\S]+[.](html|htm|svg|js|css|png|gif|jpg|jpeg))" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot/{R:1}" />
        </rule> 

        <rule name="empty-root-index" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^$" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot/index.html" />
        </rule>

        <!-- 
             Make sure you have a <base href="/" /> tag to fix the root path 
             or all relative links will break on rewrite 
        -->
        <rule name="AngularJS-Html5-Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/.well-known/openid-configuration" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/.well-known/jwks" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/api(.*)" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/swagger(.*)" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/account(.*)" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/connect(.*)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot/index.html"  />
        </rule> 
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <handlers>
      <add name="StaticFileModuleHtml" path="*.htm*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" />
      <add name="StaticFileModuleSvg" path="*.svg" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" />
      <add name="StaticFileModuleJs" path="*.js" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" />
      <add name="StaticFileModuleCss" path="*.css" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" />
      <add name="StaticFileModuleJpeg" path="*.jpeg" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" />
      <add name="StaticFileModuleJpg" path="*.jpg" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" />
      <add name="StaticFileModulePng" path="*.png" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" />
      <add name="StaticFileModuleGif" path="*.gif" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" />
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" 
                stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

With this configuration in the web config, my vue js application runs fine. But then when I go the site: http(s)://[MYWEBAPP]/swagger, it redirects to http(s)://[MYWEBAPP]/swagger/index.html and gives a 404 files not found error.

Configure Service in my startup class looks like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Sample API")
    );

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
        
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();
    
    app.UseAuthentication();  
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
       endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
       name: "default",
       pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Trying through the multiple available solutions, I realized that the swagger UI is trying to look for the index.html from the wwwroot, so it is causing the not found error. I am stuck on how to suggest swagger UI to look into the own directory.

What could be the issues with this? What am i missing here? Anyone else also might have this issue?

Comment: were you able to fix the issue? I know its because of the handlers. But handlers are required for spa to work. I have tried the solution mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48889816/iis-rewrite-exclude-folders-and-subfolders-swagger-case/48893301#48893301 but still no luck

Comment: I have also tried the same, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same problem with my React application. To pass swagger request to .Net application IIS has to do following:

1. Not rewrite URL starting with `swagger`
2. Select correct handler based on its `path` attribute

My web.config looks similar to this xml. Important is first rewrite rule and handler for `swagger/*` path.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="swagger" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="swagger/.*" />
          </rule>

          <rule name="HTTPS force" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
              <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
          </rule>

          <rule name="wwwroot-static" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="([\S]+[.](.+))" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot/{R:1}" />
          </rule>

          <rule name="empty-root-index" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^$" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot/index.html" />
          </rule>

          <rule name="React-Html5-Routes" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="api/(.*)" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot/index.html" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>

      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCoreSwagger" path="swagger/*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        <add name="StaticFileModule" path="*.*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" />
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>

      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\API.dll" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```