# How do I exclude verbs in ASP.NET Core API?

Tags: asp.net-core, web-config, asp.net-core-webapi, http-verbs

I need to exclude verbs allowed for an API solution, but I can't find examples how to do it in `web.config`.

I did find [an example for MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509770/how-do-i-exclude-things-that-match-the-specified-path-for-an-httphandler-in-asp) that looks like this:

```
<configuration>
 <system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
   <remove verb="*" path="MyPage.aspx" type="MyHandler, MyAssembly"/>
   <add verb="*" path="MyPage.aspx" type="MySpecialHandler, MyAssembly"/>
  </httpHandlers>
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Is this how I should do it for an API as well?

If so, what should I put in the place of `path`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core, implementation of HTTP handlers and modules are replaced by Middleware. This article has enough information how to migrate from HTTP handlers and modules to ASP.NET Core middleware.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/http-modules

In order to achieve HTTP verbs exclusion from your API, you can write a simple middleware like this:

```
public class VerbsMiddleware{

        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private string[] VerbsToExclude = {"DELETE", "PUT"}; //You can put these in appsettings.json

        public VerbsMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context){

            if (VerbsToExclude.Contains(context.Request.Method))
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 405;
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Method Not Allowed");
            }

            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }

    }
```

With  the above middleware, you API returns status code of `405` for any `HttpDelete` and `HttpPut` requests.

Comment: Thanks @Yared. My only suggestion is to change it from VerbsToExclude to VerbsToInclude and reverse the if statement. That way you specify the ones you know you handle, and everything else is blocked

Comment: how to exclude verbs on appsetting.json file ?